# Unable to build react native project after updating to xcode 11.0

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, core-data, xcode11

I have a react native project running on react native version 0.59.8 , and xcode version 10.3. Somehow my xcode got updated to version 11.0 and after that i am unable to build the project using `react-native run-ios` command.

I have tried cleaning up the build and building again. But that doesn't help.

I am getting the following error:

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPackaging.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XRPackageModel.momd/XRPackageModel 9.0.omo'
error Could not find iPhone X simulator.
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463536/coredata-annotation-failed-to-load-optimized-model-react-native and also refer https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/issues/167

Comment: I've got the same error. How are we going to fix this?

Comment: I have tried these things @rizwan, but doesn't seem to be fixing the issue. issue is something related to the new data model introduced, i guess!

Comment: @GaneshKrishna you could try and directly run react-native app from Xcode instead of react-native-run-ios.

Comment: @GaneshKrishna start your IPhoneX simulator first and then run the project.

Comment: I have tried these steps as well, doesn't seem to work! - @Rizwan

Comment: Duplicate question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207838/react-native-run-ios-could-not-find-iphone-x-simulator-xrpackagemodel-9-0-omo/58266877#58266877

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about the first error, but I have same problem for second error `error Could not find iPhone X simulator`after upgrade to XCode 11

Basically I changed the line 53 in the react native project `/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js`, from `simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES'` to `simulator.isAvailable !== true`.

The root cause is new XCode 11 changed the simulator metadata format, and react native findMatchingSimulator method is strongly coupled to the previous format.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same issue but don't have the file `findMatchingSimulator.js` to edit at all. I'm on react-native 0.59.10. What version is this solution for?

Comment: @shinlos With RN 0.59.9 , you can find this file in `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/runIOS/`

Comment: The second error is not the issue, i am not able to build the project because of first error.

Comment: Line 36 if you're on older versions or React Native. Also, thanks!!

Comment: Issue is with not finding .omo files. How to generate or add them?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix the "Could not find iPhone X simulator" error.

These are the steps to fix the above error:

Run the command `find . -iname findMatchingSimulator.js` to locate `findMatchingSimulator.js` file.

In this file, Change the code from

```
if (simulator.availability !== '(available)' && simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES') {
        continue;
      }
```

to

```
if (simulator.availability !== '(available)' && simulator.isAvailable !== true) {
        continue;
      }
```

By doing this simulator error is resolved. But Still the other error

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPackaging.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XRPackageModel.momd/XRPackageModel 9.0.omo'
```

exists, which makes the build to fail. If I install xcode 10.3 and run the command `react-native run-ios`, it still works. 
Hope the issue is clear. Any fixes for this issue which occurs in xcode 11?

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

- With Xcode 11, make sure you're using react-native-community/cli **version 1.9.8 minimum**, as it integrates the fix for Xcode 11 simulators new metadata format:

  https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/releases/tag/v1.9.8
- Also, the iPhone X simulator is no longer available at least on my end. You can use an iPhone 11 instead :

```
react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 11'
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case:

```
react: 16.8.3
react-native: 0.59.9
Xcode: 11.0
```

1. Add iPhone X simulator: Open Xcode => Window => Devices and Simulators => Simulators => Press Plus button at the bottom
2. Install latest version of cocoapods: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
3. Re-Install cocoapods in project: Open project folder => ios => delete `Podfile.lock`, `Pods` folder, `build` folder => `cd ios && pod install`
4. `react-native run-ios` Done!

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading my XCode to version 11, in XCode simulators list it only shows ios 13 simulators as available, so we need to add previous version simulators, to do so, in XCode go to preferences -> Components -> and download and install a previous version ios simulator (ios 11.0 in my case), after doing so it must show other simulators in available simulator list. Clear all cache and re-run the react-native run-ios command and it should work now.

Comment: I have posted the updates above! still facing the issue in xcode 11. works fine if i go back to xcode 10.3! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try run specifying simulator version.

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11 Pro Max"
```

Comment: It looks like an issue with .omo file, i was able to fix the "Could not find iPhone X simulator" error.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded `"react-native"` to `"^0.61.1"` and it worked for me

Comment: This may work, but i cant update to ^0.61 as of now, looking for a work-around for the 0.59.8 version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, and even went back to xCode 10.3....and still had the same issue. Then I came across this https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/414 . Sounded to me like maybe they had fixed the issue and that I was running with an old version of the CLI. Proceeded to delete the entry in my lock file and run npm install. Working now. CLI is up to 1.11.2 https://github.com/react-native-community/cli

Answer (score 0):

Run can run `xcrun simctl list devices` in a terminal to make sure you have the iPhone X simulator installed. If you can't see it in the list you need to add it to Xcode through `Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators` (click the + in the bottom left)